# Automatic login in web app if user is already logged in Google Apps

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I would like to know the best way of implementing automatic login to my web site. What I mean by automatic is this:

I've already signed into Google. I now go to my web site and its login page. Instead of clicking on the link to login with Google I would like the web app to detect that I'm already logged into Google and bypass the whole login page.

How can we do this using PHP and lightopenid?

Comment: May be this is what you looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874186/login-to-site-using-gmail